# ASP.NET Binding with EVAL

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, data-binding

I'm trying to do the following for asp.net combobox:

```
Text='<%# IIf(Eval("Name").ToString().Equals(""), Bind("Other"), Bind("Name") %>'
```

What I'm trying to do is if the "Name" column is empty then bind to "Other" column, otherwise bind to "Name" column.

Anyone know the right syntax, keep getting object not set to reference.  I'm doing this in VB.Net.

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: maybe one of the fields is null, that's why you're getting that error.

Comment: what version of .NET are you targeting? 2, 3.5 or 4?

Answer (score 4):

Try this (Edited)

```
Text='<%# If(Not Eval("Name").ToString.Length = 0, Eval("Name") , Eval("Other")) %>'
```

If this doesn't work, then you might have to build a Code Behind method

```
Text='<%# RetrieveName(Eval("Name"),Eval("Other"))'
```

Code Behind

```
Public Function RetrieveName(Byval name As String?, Byval other As String?) As String
  If Not String.IsDBNull(name) Then
    return name
  ElseIf String.IsDBNull(name) AndAlso Not String.IsDBNull(other) Then
    return other
  Else
    return String.Empty
  End If
End Function
```

Comment: Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'String' is not valid.

Comment: ah object not set to an instance

Comment: sorry, I forgot to add "As String" to the end of the function - fixed now.

Comment: So, in what you're testing.. Name is obviously NULL  ;-)

Comment: I think I'm going to give on this one 
Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'String' is not valid.

Comment: did that function not work? Is Name and Other in the database actually Strings (varchar, etc)?

Comment: I did one more edit using `IsDBNull`, though I'm not sure if it's supported in VB.NET 2 since I haven't used V2 in a very long time.

Comment: Also please forgive me if there are minor typos... I'm on my mac and don't have VS in front of me for formatting and intellisense.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Text='<%# IIf(Eval("Name").Equals(DBNull.Value), Eval("Other") , Eval("Name")) %>'
```

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. I get that error? column can contain Null, how should I be dealing with that?

Comment: you need to do something like Eval("Name").Equals(DBNull.Value), in c# there is string.IsNullOrEmpty function...not sure with VB.

Comment: Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'String' is not valid.