# Eval and IsNullOrEmpty issue

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm new to VB and ASP and I have a question regarding writing a proper IF statement for my aspx page.

I am able to get the result i need if I use <%#Eval()"Bedrooms" %> however, my If statement does not like the Eval databinding.

```
<% 
  If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("Bedrooms"))) Then
   String.Format("<li>Bedrooms: " + Eval("Bedrooms").ToString + "</li>")
  Else
   String.Format("EMPTY")
  End If
%>
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can write this properly

Comment: try whether this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200111/asp-net-binding-with-eval

Comment: Please note that the string concatenation operator in VB.NET is `&`, not `+`.

Answer (score 1):

Best way is probably to use a function instead, but try

```
<% If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("Bedrooms"),
          "Empty", 
          "<li>Bedrooms:" + Eval("Bedrooms") + "</li>") %>
```